# Вывод строк по id на статьи

Tags: php, get, redbeanphp

Здраствуйте! Начал изучать PHP и RedBean PHP. Прошу помощы у вас. Буду благодарен за помощь! Мне нужно вывести название новости, которое равно id новости. Текст новости, который равен id новости.
Вывод статьи на главной:

```
$query = R::findAll('posts', ' ORDER BY id DESC');

        foreach ($query as $posts){
            echo '  <div class="col-news">
                    <img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="foreword">
                            <a href="/post.php?post_id='.$posts['id'].'">'.mb_substr($posts['title'], 0, 45).'</a>
                            <p>'.mb_substr($posts['content'], 0, 340), '...'.'</p>
                        </div>
                </div>';
        }
```

Сам пост:

```
$query = R::find('posts');

        foreach ($query as $posts){
            echo '  <section class="container-fluid section-post">
                        <div class="header-menu">
                            <a href="index.php" class="logo">Wires</a>
                            <div class="header-button">
                                <a href="index.php" class="button" style="margin: 0 30px 0 30px;">На главную</a>
                                <a href="signup.php" class="button login">Войти / Регистрация</a>
                                <a href="logout.php" class="button logout">Выйти</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content-post active">
                            <h1 class="title-content">'.$posts['title'].'</h1>
                            <img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="" class="img-posts">
                            <p>'.$posts['content'].'</p>
                        </div> 
                    </section>'

                        ;
        }
```

Comment: `findOne('posts','id=?',[$id]);`

Comment: выдает "Неопределенная переменная $id"

Comment: Ну так объявите её и засуньте в нее идентификатор нужной новости